# How I add/update and remove a object and list them in components with data normalized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I've been trying to understand how to add / update and remove objects in normalized data with normalizr for a long time, this is my response normalized :

```
entities:
   profile:
   1: {id: 1, full_name: "Dedaldino Antonio", short_name: "Dedaldino", created_at: "2020-03-11T12:51:09.822352Z", updated_at: "2020-03-12T11:51:48.444694Z", …}
   6: {id: 6, full_name: "", short_name: "", created_at: "2020-03-11T14:50:50.549222Z", updated_at: "2020-03-11T14:50:50.549222Z", …}
   7: {id: 7, full_name: "", short_name: "", created_at: "2020-03-11T14:55:05.924225Z", updated_at: "2020-03-11T14:55:05.924225Z", …}
   8: {id: 8, full_name: "Majaa Antonio", short_name: "Majaa", created_at: "2020-03-11T15:03:46.625055Z", updated_at: "2020-03-12T09:45:45.594663Z", …}
   user:
   1: {user_id: 1, username: "dedaldino", email: "dedaldinoantonio7@gmail.com", phone_number: "925956139", followers_count: 3, …}
   6: {user_id: 6, username: "a", email: "a@mail.com", phone_number: null, followers_count: 1, …}
   7: {user_id: 7, username: "dorkal", email: "dorkal@noreply.com", phone_number: null, followers_count: 0, …}
   8: {user_id: 8, username: "maja", email: "maja@mail.com", phone_number: "923652343", followers_count: 2, …}
   comments: {5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}, 10: {…}, 11: {…}, 12: {…}, 13: {…}, 14: {…}, 15: {…}, 16: {…}, 17: {…}, 18: {…}, 19: {…}, 20: {…}, 21: {…}, 22: {…}, 23: {…}, 24: {…}, 25: {…}, 26: {…}, 27: {…}, 28: {…}, 29: {…}, 30: {…}, 31: {…}, 32: {…}, 33: {…}, 34: {…}, 35: {…}, 36: {…}, 37: {…}, 38: {…}}
   post:
   6: {id: 6, file: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/26870321-background-wi…e-background-of-technology-and-hacker_MPbb0zm.jpg", location: "Luanda, Angola", content: "Uma das maiores implantações de PostgreSQL no Bras… sistema contam com mais de 70 milhões de linhas.", comment_count: 17, …}
   7: {id: 7, file: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/159703_pj0Otst.jpg", location: "Moscovo", content: "Uma das maiores implantações de PostgreSQL no Bras… sistema contam com mais de 70 milhões de linhas.", comment_count: 8, …}
   8: {id: 8, file: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/334_3xeCIpk.jpg", location: "Wuhuan, China",      content: "Handling data in a React.js application is super e…t always obvious how you should update your view.", comment_count: 9, …}
   result: (5) [8, 8, 7, 6, 6]
```

But a post's response is more nested.
I want to know how I use this data in the components,
I thought about how to use them in components, my mapToProps looks like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
user: () => {
    const user_id = state.feed.entities.comments[ownProps.comment_id].user
    return state.feed.entities.user[user_id]
},
profile:() => {
    const id = state.feed.entities.comments[ownProps.comment_id].user
    return state.feed.entities.user[user_id]
},
comment: state.feed.entities.comments })
```

but this is very complex, normalizing should make my life easier

I searched the documents and issues on github, I read about selectors but I don't know how to add them and where they will be

Should I create selectors or is there another way to make it simpler?

**I want to list a post (with user that posted) and comments, and each comment with your user and profile_image**

HELP ME